# How to give my paid app to someone for free

Tags: iphone

I have an app on the app store which is a paid-for app.  Is there a way of giving my app away to certain people via email for free?

I don't mean 'gifting it' because that would cost me 30%.  I mean completely free for both parties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to iTunes Connect and generate some promo codes. There's a limit of 50 for each release and there are some limitations, for example users can't add reviews in iTunes.

*Update*: In 2013, Apple upped the number of promo codes for each version of your app from 50 to 100.

Comment: I'd say the biggest limitation is that the promo codes expire after four weeks. That means you're not really "giving away" the app to someone, just loaning it to them. It's unfortunate and a bit silly that Apple won't let you give your own app away for promotional purposes.

Comment: @BourbonJockey The _codes_ expire in four weeks but the app does not. If you redeem the code within that four week window you get to keep it.

Comment: Wow, I had totally misread the docs on that. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 ways to do this.

1. As stated above, give the recipient a promo code from iTunesConnect.
2. If you can build it for the recipient in person you can add their device as a developer device and build directly onto their device.
3. Temporarily change your app's price to free for the recipient to download from the app store.
4. Use Xcode to create an ad-hoc build of the app, which could just be sent to the recipient.